# how to visualise solenoidal vector field?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-fields

How to visualise solenoidal vector field;I am thinking it as a solenoid going  in a circular fashion with propagation in the z direction.[image: soul]

I was solving a problem to check that field is solenoidal or not ?

Comment: I think you can use the fact that the net flux of a solenoidal field over any closed surface is $0$.